# Connecting to Redis hosted in docker on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, docker, redis

I have just setup redis using docker in windows and I am trying to write a simple .Net console app to connect to it to familiarize myself with things.

I am running docker in windows 10 pro using "docker run redis:windowsservercore"

The redis instance looks like it boots up fine and will display:

***[1904] 21 Mar 13:18:50.835 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.100***

***[1904] 21 Mar 13:18:50.847 - The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379***

But in my app when I try to connect to localhost:6379 it seems as if it can't find the redis instance at all:

```
var log = new StringWriter();
try
{
    StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer RedisConnection = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379", log); // This line errors
    var cache = RedisConnection.GetDatabase(1);
    cache.StringSet("Test", "Hello World");
    Console.WriteLine(cache.StringGet("Test"));
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

The connection above always fails with:

"It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect on localhost:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 2s ago, last-write: 2s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 9s ago, v: 2.1.0.1"

I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I have tried connecting using other naming methods for localhost. I disabled all firewalls for public and private networks to ensure this wasn't the issue.

I am note sure what I need to do here to get a connection established, hopefully someone has some advice for me.

Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: Just at a quick glance, what if you include the schema? `http://localhost:6379` Or even test with `http://127.0.0.1:6379`. Also, have you confirmed that port 6379 successfully opened on your host machine?

Comment: You need to publish ports to the host while running the container : `docker run -p 6379:6379 redis:windowsservercore`

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions already but thank you for the input.

It turns out the issue was that I was attempting to use the redis:windowsservercore but instead I was able to get everything working following the instructions here:

[redis docker walkthrough](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/getting-started/docker/getting-started-docker/).

I thought I had tried this already but the key point I was missing was when I converted my docker to use linux containers docker ran out of memory and was failing to start. Expanding docker to 3gb instead of the default 2gb solved this.